# bootstrap modal onclick closing

Tags: laravel, forms

I have form to submit signon inside a modal. It is not allowing me to enter email and password. When I click on the form element it is closing.What am I doing wrong here.It is supposed to enter the email and password to submit

**Form Modal**

```
    <div id="click_signin" class="modal  New-Bouncing-popup" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog bounce animated modal-ku">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6 left-side">
                        <h1>Surplus<br>Forex.</h1>
                        <p>Build your profitable forex career.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>Login with social media</p>
                        <a class="fb" href="#" target="_blank">Login With Facebook</a>
                        <a class="tw" href="#" target="_blank">Login With Twitter</a>

                    </div><!--col-sm-6-->

                    <div class="col-sm-6 right-side">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <p>Fill the below given fields to Login</p>
                        <br/>
                        <!--Form with header-->
                        <div class="form">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form2">Your email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="form2" class="form-control">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form4">Your password</label>
                                <input type="password" id="form4" class="form-control">

                            </div>

                            <div class="text-xs-center frm_grp">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank">Login</a>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <!--/Form with header-->

                    </div><!--col-sm-6-->



                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it closing when you click on the form or the elements inside the form? Or both?

Comment: pionter-event was causing it to close modal